# Dart - Abstract constructors

Tags: inheritance, dart

Say I have the abstract class A

```dart
abstract class A {
  A.someConstructor(Foo foo);
}
```

and all subclasses of A should then implement such constructor:

```dart
class B extends A {
  @override
  B.someConstructor(Foo foo) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

So basically what I want is some kind of abstract constructors.

Is there any way of achieving this (of course the above code does not work) or do I need a normal abstract method which then creates the object and sets its properties?

EDIT: Ok so it looks like the only way to create at least a similar behaviour would be something like this:

```dart
abstract class A {
  A.someConstructor(Object foo);
}

class B extends A {
  B.someConstructor(Object foo) : super.someConstructor(foo) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This isn't exactly useful, and after some thinking about my problem I realized that in fact my original goal itself is not really neccessary, so this questions is now answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to enforce a pattern on the constructors of subclasses. The Dart language has no support for doing that.

Dart has *types* and *interfaces* which can be used to restrict values and class instance members.

If a class implements an interface, then its *instance* members must satisfy the signatures declared by the super-interface. This restricts instance members.

If a variable has a type, for example a function type, then you can only assign values of that type to it. This restricts *values*. Because a class is a subtype of its interfaces, the subclass restriction means that class typed variables can be used safely (the subtype can be used as its supertype because it has a compatible interface).

There is no way to restrict static members or constructors of classes, or members of libraries, because there is no way to abstract over them. You always have to refer directly to them by their precise name, so there is no *need* for them to match a particular pattern.
(Which may explain why you found the goal not necessary too).

In this situation, your subclasses *must* call the `A.someConstructor` constructor, but they are free to choose the signature of their own constructors. They can do:

```
class B extends A {
  B.someConstructor(Object foo) : super.someConstructor(foo);
}
// or
class C extends A {
  C.differentName(Object foo) : super.someConstructor(foo);
}
// or even
class D extends A {
  D() : super.someConstructor(new Object());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Constructors aren’t inherited**
>
> Subclasses don’t inherit constructors from their superclass. A
>   subclass that declares no constructors has only the default (no
>   argument, no name) constructor.

[Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors)

Comment: well I dont want to inherit a constructor, but to declare an abstract one, which all subclasses *have* to implement themselves

Comment: Then you should use `implements` instead of `extends`. But this still won't work with constructors.