# How to enforce Implements constraint on generic type T in generic Dart method?

Tags: flutter, generics, dart

## What I'm trying to achieve

I am trying to create a generic Dart method that takes a generic type T where T has to implement class IModel. However,

## Problem

It seems like I can't set an `implements` constraint on type T, only an `extends`. For example `<T implements IModel` does not work but `<T extends IModel>` works.

## Code

IModel.dart which serves as an interface:

```
class IModel {
  IModel();

  factory IModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return IModel();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {};

  IModel clone() {
    return IModel();
  }
}
```

MyModel.dart, an example that implements IModel:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:.../helpers/DateTimeHelper.dart';
import 'package:.../helpers/StringHelper.dart';
import 'package:.../models/IModel.dart';

class MyModel implements IModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  String companyId;
  String projectId;
  String description;
  DateTime created;
  DateTime updated;

  MyModel({this.id, this.name, this.description, this.created, this.updated, this.companyId, this.projectId});

  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyModel(id: json["id"], name: json["name"], created: DateTime.parse(json["created"]), updated: DateTime.parse(json["updated"]), description: json["description"], companyId: json["companyId"], projectId: json["projectId"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Id": id,
        "Name": name,
        "Description": description,
        "CompanyId": companyId,
        "ProjectId": projectId,
        "Created": created.toIso8601String(),
        "Updated": updated.toIso8601String()
      };

  MyModel clone() {
    return new MyModel(id: StringHelper.clone(id), companyId: StringHelper.clone(companyId), created: DateTimeHelper.clone(created), updated: DateTimeHelper.clone(updated), name: StringHelper.clone(name), projectId: StringHelper.clone(projectId), description: StringHelper.clone(description));
  }
}
```

ModelHelper.dart with the generic method:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:.../models/IModel.dart';

// 'T implements IModel' not working, but 'T extends IModel' does as constraint.
abstract class ModelHelper {
  static List<T> listFromJson<T implements IModel>(String json) {
    List l = jsonDecode(json)["data"];
    var models = l.map((m) => T.fromJson(m)).toList();
    return models;
  }
}
```

## Additional questions/conclusion

Are `implements` constraints not supported in Dart? Do all T classes simply have to extend IModel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ## Problem
>
> It seems like I can't set an implements constraint on type T, only an extends. For example <T implements IModel does not work but  works.

This is not a problem. You can safely use `<T extends IModel>`, even for classes that *implements* `IModel`:

```dart
abstract class Abstract {}

class Concrete implements Abstract {}

void function<T extends Abstract>(T value) {
  print(value);
}

void main() {
  function<Concrete>(Concrete()); // works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way to specify an `implements` constraint for a generic type argument, and such a constraint should never be necessary.  Given:

   ```dart
   class Base {}
   class Derived1 extends Base {}
   class Derived2 implements Base {}

   void genericFunction<T extends Base>() {}
   ```

   the generic type constraint `T extends Base` means that the type argument  *derives* from `Base`.  It does not (and *should not*) require that the type argument uses the `extends` keyword.  Whether the type argument uses `extends` or `implements` is an implementation detail of that class (`Derived1` or `Derived2` in this example) and should be of no concern to the generic (`genericFunction`) itself.  Instances of `Derived1` and of `Derived2` both provide the same interface as `Base` regardless of whether they use `extends` or `implements`, and that's all that matters.
2. Even if there were an `implements` constraint for generic type arguments, it wouldn't do what you want.  You have the misunderstanding that `Derived implements Base` will provide the same constructors or `static` methods as `Base`.  **In Dart, constructors and `static` methods are not part of the class's interface.**  They are not inheritable.  For example:

   ```dart
   class Base {
     Base.namedConstructor();

     static void staticMethod() {}
   }

   class Derived implements Base {} // Perfectly legal.

   void main() {
     var d = Derived(); // Legal.
     d = Derived.namedConstructor(); // ERROR
     Derived.staticMethod(); // ERROR
   }
   ```

   There is no way for a generic to require that a type argument have a particular constructor or `static` method and therefore there is no way to invoke constructors or `static` methods on type arguments.  In general, you instead would need to pass a *callback* that invokes the desired constructor or `static` method.  Specifically for serializing/deserializing JSON, you should use an existing package that utilizes code-generation (such as [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)) instead of trying to implement it yourself.

Also see:

- [Dart - Abstract constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58223010/)