# How can I enforce "implements" in a generic type and use the a constructor from the generic in Dart?

Tags: dart, generics

I want to create a generic that would implement a interface and operate on this type, even calling one of it's constructors.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve:

```dart
void main() {
    var aToto = Toto();
      
      aToto.FooBarUser<Foo>("testing Foo");
      aToto.FooBarUser<Bar>("testing Bar");
    }
    
    class Foo {
        late String _myString;  
        Foo.fromString(this._myString);
    
        String toTheWorld() {
            return _myString;
        }
    }
    
    class Bar implements Foo {
        late String _myString;
        Bar.fromString(String aString) {
            _myString = "Bar: $aString";
        }
    
      @override
        String toTheWorld() {
            return _myString;
        }
    }
    
    class Toto {
        T FooBarUser<T extends Foo> (String aString) {
            var myInstance = T.fromString(aString);
        
            print(myInstance.toTheWorld());
        
            return myInstance;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly Dart doesn't allows me to do it as *implements* isn't supported in generic types, only extends.

I tried the solution presented in [How to enforce Implements constraint on generic type T in generic Dart method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264987/how-to-enforce-implements-constraint-on-generic-type-t-in-generic-dart-method) (using *extends* instead of *implements*) but Dart says that

> The method 'fromString' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

How can I create a generic similar to *FooBarUser* in Dart?

Comment: "Unfortunatelly Dart doesn't allows me to do it as implements isn't supported in generic types, only extends." Even if Dart allowed `T implements Foo` as a constraint for generic type parameters, it would be no different from `T extends Foo` and wouldn't do what you want. In Dart, constructors and `static` methods are not part of a class's interface, so there is no way to enforce that a type has a particular constructor or `static` method, and there is way to invoke one generically.  At best you can make `FooBarUser` take a `fromString` callback instead.

Comment: I've added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77440496/) to the question you mentioned which elaborates a bit more on my comment above.